# How to set an image height & width on a video in ffmpeg

Tags: image, ffmpeg

I have many videos and I need to put an image in them for about 20 seconds, I am adding them manually and it works fine if only the image is small in size....
please, help me out to set height and width on the image

The original command is this

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -i 3.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy tout.mkv pause
```

But it give me output as these image below

[Image - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM5Zb.jpg)
[Image - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4xko.jpg)

Comment: What's wrong with the output?

Answer (score 0):

Put `-s WxH` just before `-pix_fmt yuv420p`. i.e. `-s 1920x1080`.

Comment: The [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filter is more flexible than `-s` (which uses the scale filter anyway), and it can be placed in the desired order within the filtergraph. Same for the [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format-1) filter and `-pix_fmt`.